# Entity Framework 4.0 + Configurable ProviderManifestToken

Tags: entity-framework-4

We have built a product around EF4 with POCO and the initial requirements were to work against SQLServer 2005. However, we have a few clients who have SQLServer2008 installed. Hence, at runtime, we need to verify the version of the DB and make changes to the manifest token in the edmx accordingly. Or, can it be done to read the ProviderManifestToken from a web.config and build the edmx at runtime. Our client doesn't want one installer per DB version.

Thanks,Murali

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the actual database is SqlServer2008 you can still have a ProviderManifestToken value of `2005`. So unless you are building two different versions of your software, where one targets (and uses the features of) SqlServer2008, you can just keep it as is.